# Copying and renaming files to a single directory by a single shell script

Tags: shell-script, rename, file-copy

I have multiple files with an example of how they look like shown below.

```
-rw-r--r--   1 my_user     users           12 Dec 13 09:56 Example_30_001_20130913175000.DAT  
-rw-r--r--   1 my_user     users           12 Dec 13 09:57 Example_30_002_20130913180854.DAT  
-rw-r--r--   1 my_user     users           12 Dec 13 09:58 Example_30_003_20130913180857.DAT  
-rw-r--r--   1 my_user     users           12 Dec 13 09:58 Example_30_004_20130913180901.DAT  
-rw-r--r--   1 my_user     users           12 Dec 13 09:59 Example_30_005_20130913180904.DAT  
-rw-r--r--   1 my_user     users           12 Dec 13 10:02 Example_30_006_20130913180907.DAT  
-rw-r--r--   1 my_user     users           12 Dec 13 09:59 Example_30_007_20130913180911.DAT
```

My question is how do I copy them in the same directory and rename the copied files using a sh script such that they start with something like the filenames shown below?

```
Ex_Example_001.DAT  
Ex_Example_002.DAT  
Ex_Example_003.DAT  
Ex_Example_004.DAT  
Ex_Example_005.DAT  
Ex_Example_006.DAT  
Ex_Example_007.DAT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute this in the folder of your files:

```
find . -type f -name "Example_30*.DAT" | awk -F\_ '{printf "cp -v %s Ex_Example_%s.DAT\n", $0, $3}' | bash
```

- `find . -type f`: search only for files
- `-name "Example_30*.DAT"`: file beginning with "Example_30" and ending with ".DAT"
- `| awk -F\_`: pipe this to `awk` and set the delimiter to `_`
- `'{printf "cp -v %s Ex_Example_%s.DAT\n", $0, $3}'`: generate a command like this: `cp -v oldname newname`
- `| bash`: and pipe this to `bash` to execute it

Output should look like this:

```
»./Example_30_002_20130913180854.DAT“ -> »Ex_Example_002.DAT“
»./Example_30_005_20130913180904.DAT“ -> »Ex_Example_005.DAT“
»./Example_30_003_20130913180857.DAT“ -> »Ex_Example_003.DAT“
»./Example_30_006_20130913180907.DAT“ -> »Ex_Example_006.DAT“
»./Example_30_007_20130913180911.DAT“ -> »Ex_Example_007.DAT“
»./Example_30_004_20130913180901.DAT“ -> »Ex_Example_004.DAT“
»./Example_30_001_20130913175000.DAT“ -> »Ex_Example_001.DAT“
```

**Edit:**

> What if I want it to be put in a script outside of that folder? How
>   would I go about doing it?

Create a file called `script`. Add the following lines into that file:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIRECTORY=/path/to/dir/
cd $DIRECTORY
find . -type f -name "Example_30*.DAT" | awk -F\_ '{printf "cp -v %s Ex_Example_%s.DAT\n", $0, $3}' | bash
cd -
```

Make the script executable:

```
chmod u+x script
```

And then call the script:

```
./script
```

or

```
/absolute/path/to/script
```

Comment: What if I want it to be put in a script outside of that folder? How would I go about doing it?

Comment: @CHT in your script execute `cd /path/to/dir` prior to the command above, and `cd -` after, to go back to the prevous directory.

Comment: If you have an example of how that new code would be implemented in the current code, I would really appreciate that.  
  
Edit: I'm new to this, thus I need the example so as to see how it would connect.

Comment: @CHT: see my edit

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I have read it through and from what I understand, it's supposed to first change to the directory of the files, then "find and replace" the names of the files and finally going back to the original folder it came from. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: What if I want to preserve a copy of the original files as the original names though?

Comment: The file get copied, so the original files preserve also with the original names

Comment: I apparently don't have bash, while only having ksh. Is there a workabout that I can use to make this run?

Comment: It also works with `ksh`, just replace `bash` at the end with `ksh`.

Comment: This particular Unix keeps finding fault with the commands in the printf command though.

Comment: OK, please post the errors, and the output of the first part of the command: `find . -type f -name "Example_30*.DAT" | awk -F\_ '{printf "cp -v %s Ex_Example_%s.DAT\n", $0, $3}'`

Comment: Basically, it's the line below repeated 7 times.  
  
    cp: illegal option -- v
    Usage:  cp [-f|-i] [-p] [-S] [-e warn|force|ignore] source_file target_file
        cp [-f|-i] [-p] [-S] [-e warn|force|ignore] source_file ... target_directory
        cp [-f|-i] [-p] [-S] -R|-r [-e warn|force|ignore] source_directory ... target_directory
        cp -R[-H | -L | -P] [-f|-i] [-p] [-S] [-e warn|force|ignore] source_file ... target
        cp -r[-H | -L | -P] [-f|-i] [-p] [-S] [-e warn|force|ignore] source_file ... target

Comment: Your `cp` implementaion don't know the option `-v` so remove it from the `cp` command: it's just the verboity flag. The new command: `find . -type f -name "Example_30*.DAT" | awk -F\_ '{printf "cp %s Ex_Example_%s.DAT\n", $0, $3}' | ksh`

Comment: That fixed it. Sorry for the trouble, and I really appreciate what you have done to guide me.

Comment: No problem, ur welcome.

Comment: Sorry for having to ask yet again, but if I were to put this in a if-else command, would the code below work?  
  
    if [[find . -type f -name "Example_30*.DAT" = true]]
    then
        find . -type f -name "Example_30*.DAT" | awk -F\_ '{printf "cp %s Ex_Example_30_%s.DAT\n", $0, $3}' | ksh  
    else  
        printf "Error."

Answer (score 1):

In zsh:

```
autoload -U zmv
zmv -C -o -p '/path/to/source/directory/(Example_)[0-9]##_([0-9]##)_20130913175000(.DAT)' '/path/to/destination/directory/Ex_$1$2$3'
```

In other shells:

```
cd /path/to/source/directory/
for source in Example_*_*_*.DAT; do
  tail=${source##*/}
  target=Ex_${tail%%_*}; tail=${tail#*_}
  tail=${tail#*_}
  target=${tail%%_*}.${tail##*.}
  cp -p "$source" "target"
done
```

Comment: While your answer is good, I am a newbie in Unix, meaning I won't understand why your answer is so. Therefore, the best answer would have to go to the other person. Sorry for the trouble.